# text going bottom of the article

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to have some text next to an image but when I put a text after the image it goes down and doesn't stay in the top of the article.

```css
* {
            margin: 0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        * a:link {
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        body {
            background-color: #f5f5f5;
            height: 100%;
            min-height: 100%;
        }
        article{
            background-color: #ffffff;
            width: 85%;
            padding: 10px 15px;
            text-align: right;
            direction: rtl;
            border-radius: 3px;
            margin: 20px auto;
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
            -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
            box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
        }
        img{
            border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
            display: inline-block;
        }
        .name{
            display: inline-block;
        }
```

```html
<body>
<article>
<img src="https://sn56.scholastic.com/content/dam/classroom-magazines/sn56/issues/2018-19/040819/picture-this-nature-s-night-light/SN56_040819_Aurora-Hero-Mobile.jpg" width="375" height="375">
        <div class="name">text</div>
</article>
</body
```

I have tried using the display as inline as well but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To place the text at the starting top position, define "vertical-align: top;" property with display: inline-block;

```css
* {
            margin: 0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        * a:link {
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        body {
            background-color: #f5f5f5;
            height: 100%;
            min-height: 100%;
        }
        article{
            background-color: #ffffff;
            width: 85%;
            padding: 10px 15px;
            text-align: right;
            direction: rtl;
            border-radius: 3px;
            margin: 20px auto;
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
            -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
            box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
        }
        img{
            border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
            display: inline-block;
            vertical-align: top;
        }
        .name{
            display: inline-block;
            vertical-align: top;
        }
```

```html
<body>
<article>
<img src="https://sn56.scholastic.com/content/dam/classroom-magazines/sn56/issues/2018-19/040819/picture-this-nature-s-night-light/SN56_040819_Aurora-Hero-Mobile.jpg" width="375" height="375">
        <div class="name">text</div>
</article>
</body
```

Comment: Is there anything else I can use if the display isn't set `inline-block` ?

Answer (score 1):

Add CSS and use vertical align property to top it might help you

Answer (score 0):

Can you please change the structure.
like:

```
<article>
<div class="name">text</div><img src="https://sn56.scholastic.com/content/dam/classroom-magazines/sn56/issues/2018-19/040819/picture-this-nature-s-night-light/SN56_040819_Aurora-Hero-Mobile.jpg" width="375" height="375">
</article>
```

add css code below:

```
.name {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-left: 5px;
}
```

Note: if you have used `display:inline-block;` then you must use `verticl-align:top;`

Answer (score 0):

You can set

```
article{
        display: flex;
}
```

```css
* {
            margin: 0;
            font-family: Iransans;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        * a:link {
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        body {
            background-color: #f5f5f5;
            height: 100%;
            min-height: 100%;
        }
        article{
            background-color: #ffffff;
            width: 85%;
            padding: 10px 15px;
            text-align: right;
            direction: rtl;
            border-radius: 3px;
            margin: 20px auto;
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
            -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
            box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
        }
        img{
            border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
            display: inline-block;
        }
        .name{
            display: inline-block;
        }
        
        article{
        display: flex;
        }
```

```html
<body>
<article>
<img src="https://sn56.scholastic.com/content/dam/classroom-magazines/sn56/issues/2018-19/040819/picture-this-nature-s-night-light/SN56_040819_Aurora-Hero-Mobile.jpg" width="375" height="375">
        <div class="name">text</div>
</article>
</body
```